# Oracle RTRIM trims more than asked for

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Does anyone know why these:

```
SELECT RTRIM('123R_CLUSTER', '_CLUSTER') -- should give '123R' 
FROM DUAL;
SELECT RTRIM('123S_CLUSTER', '_CLUSTER') -- should give '123S' 
FROM DUAL;
SELECT RTRIM('123T_CLUSTER', '_CLUSTER') -- should give '123T'
FROM DUAL;
SELECT RTRIM('123U_CLUSTER', '_CLUSTER') -- should give '123U'
FROM DUAL;
```

return '123' instead of the expected?

I'm on Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

The fun begins when you try these:

- replace 123 with anything else (no change still wrong results, i.e.
  trims one character more),
- replace "R" / "S" / "T" / "U" with anything else, (works OK)
- replace "_CLUSTER" with anything else, (works OK)
- add anything after "_CLUSTER" (no change).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear:

> The Oracle/PLSQL RTRIM function removes all specified characters from the right-hand side of a string.

So it doesn't remove the *string* `_CLUSTER` at the end of your string - it removes characters until there is one that isn't _, C, L, U, S, T, E or R. Since your postfixes are R/S/T/U, they also match the `rtrim` condition, and are removed. As would `123S_SLURTE`, for example.

As an easier to understand example,

```
rtrim('LK_123aababaabbbababbaa', 'ab') // returns LK_123
```

`rtrim` simply isn't the tool for the job at hand :)

Comment: exactly what I wanted to post :) I guess you should ALWAYS try to check up on the documentation when you're not sure or haven't been using given structure for some time

Comment: @przemo_pl The devious part is that it's exactly the kind of mistake that can live for a long, long time - it can easily appear to work just fine almost all the time. Until you make that tiny, seemingly completely irrelevant change in your data, and suddenly it breaks completely and you have no idea where to even look for the problem. Ouch.

Comment: Ugh.. Thanks. Indeed by `trim_string` they meant "a list of individual characters to be trimmed" and not "the string to be trimmed".

Answer (score 0):

And in case you want to know how to easily do this with, try this:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('123R_CLUSTER', '^(.*)_CLUSTER$', 1, 1, null, 1) from dual
union all
SELECT regexp_substr('123S_CLUSTER', '^(.*)_CLUSTER$', 1, 1, null, 1) from dual
union all
SELECT regexp_substr('123T_CLUSTER', '^(.*)_CLUSTER$', 1, 1, null, 1) from dual
union all
SELECT regexp_substr('123U_CLUSTER', '^(.*)_CLUSTER$', 1, 1, null, 1) from dual;
```

yields

```
REGEXP_SUBST
------------
123R
123S
123T
123U
```

And to decipher the function

```
regexp_substr(
     '123T_CLUSTER',    -- source_field
     '^(.*)_CLUSTER$',  -- regular expression 
                        -- to capture all characters from start of
                        -- data up to "_CLUSTER"
     1,                 -- start looking at position 1 of string
     1,                 -- which occurance to return
     null,              -- used for match behaviour
     1)                 -- return what is in first set of parentheses
```